# Typescript: Function accepting 2 Types but property doesn't exist on one of the types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that takes 2 types.

```
handleDragging(e: CustomEvent<SelectionHandleDragEventType | GridHandleDragEventType>) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    const newValue = this.computeValuesFromPosition(e.detail.x, e.detail.y, e.detail.variant);

    // other same code
})
```

the issue is that `GridHandleDragEventType` does not have a `variant` as part of the type.  In those cases, I don't mind sending `null` but I keep getting the TS issue:
`Property 'variant' does not exist on type 'GridHandleDragEventType'.` Is there a clean way to resolve this?

Comment: Suggestion: Can you make it separate events? one for selection and another for grid handle?

Comment: @JGV it's a large function with that line being the only differing part so I tried to make it a shared event to keep from duplicating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the either way, I would go with the Partial one but as you need the variant property you can use the 2nd.

```
e: CustomEvent<SelectionHandleDragEventType | Partial<GridHandleDragEventType>>
```

or

```
e: CustomEvent<SelectionHandleDragEventType | GridHandleDragEventType & {variant: null}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that takes advantage of [TypeScript's structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) to use `{ detail: { x: number, y: number, variant?: string } }` instead of `SelectionHandleDragEventType | GridHandleDragEventType`.

I'm assuming that `x` and `y` are `number` and `variant` is `string` - if those aren't the actual types of those properties, you should just be able to change this example:

```
handleDragging(e: CustomEvent<{ detail: { x: number, y: number, variant?: string } }>) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    const newValue = this.computeValuesFromPosition(e.detail.x, e.detail.y, e.detail.variant ?? null);
})
```

This also defaults `variant` to `null` for `GridHandleDragEventType`, as you mentioned, but you don't necessarily need that if `computeValuesFromPosition` handles the `variant` parameter being `undefined`.